# How can I toggle onClick var div class style without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, onclick, toggle, getelementsbyclassname

I am attempting to toggle the height of all elements with class name on button click.

Here is what I am currently using. Right now it will work onClick the first time, but wont change back on second click. When I change if statement to something NOT true, the function still fires.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeHeight() {
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('div1');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) 
{
if (elems[i].style.height = '25px'){
    elems[i].style.height = '110px';
    }
else {
      elems[i].style.height = '25px';
      document.getElementById("expand").innerHTML="[+]";
}
</script>


<style type="text/css">
.div1 {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:25px;
}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<button type="button" id="expand" onClick="changeHeight();">[+]</button>
    <div class="div1">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
        content
    </div>
</body>
```

I believe the issue is I can not get my 'else' to fire because my if is not firing properly.
Any ideas?

Thanks
-Trevor

Answer (score 0):

your `if` condition check is wrong, you need to use equality operator (`==`) and not assignment operator ( `=` ) in condition check, so change:

```
if (elems[i].style.height = '25px'){
..
```

to

```
if (elems[i].style.height == '25px'){ //use == not =
..
```

and yes the closing tag `}` of for loop is also missing, do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  if (elems[i].style.height == '25px'){
    elems[i].style.height = '110px';
  }
  else {
      elems[i].style.height = '25px';
      document.getElementById("expand").innerHTML="[+]";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use descendant selector for this kind of task. It's much easier.

http://jsfiddle.net/h7vGj/2/

```
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
        .div1 {
            overflow:hidden;
            height:25px;
        }

        .on .div1 {
            height: 110px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function foo(ele) {
            if ( !ele.state ) {
                 document.body.className = "on";
                 ele.state = true;
            }
            else {
                 document.body.className = "";
                 ele.state = false;
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="expand" onclick="foo(this);">[+]</button>
    <div class="div1">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
        content
    </div>
</body>
```

PS. Your style tag is closed by script tag.